# VBA script to capture changes made to a cell

Tags: excel, vba

In Sheet1 I have a table with data (no formulas), Range A1:R53. If I update any of the cells, I would like the entire row to be copied and pasted in Sheet2 with the new data.

I don't want the entire table to be copied over, only the row that had a cell changed and the font color to be red. The rows should be pasted in the next available row and not overwrite the previous entries.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 1):

Place this event macro in the *Sheet1* worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, N As Long

    Set rng = Range("A1:R53")
    If Intersect(rng, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 27
    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        If .Cells(1, 1).Value = "" Then
            N = 1
        Else
            N = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        End If
        Target.EntireRow.Copy .Cells(N, 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

Adjust the color to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @Gary's Student. Your code works very well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Gary's Student. Your code works very well. I apologize for not posting my code, as you can see it was copying the entire table to sheet 2 and not just each row. 

Sub macro1()

Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A60000").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

@Gary'sStudent: I just wanted to know if it's possible when i make changes to different cells within a single row, that each change is not copied over multiple times? Rather, the row with multiple changes is copied to "sheet 2" once? Hope this makes sense.